# Installing SSRS on the Sharepoint Box as opposed to the SQL Box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services, architecture

We currently have two SQl boxes (2008 R2) with multiple instances on them. One for test and the other for production databases. 
We also have two sharepoint servers (2010 Enterprise). One in the DMZ hosting the Extranet Web App and the other in our local domain hosting the intranet web aplpication.

1. It makes sense to install SSRS on Sharepoint Server hosting the extranet for security purposes, although I have it installed on the SQl box with a native sharepoint installation to support integrated mode.
2. On the other hand I am guessing I can install SSRS on the SQl box or the Sharepoint Server when it comes to the Intranet web app.

In both cases here is my Question:
Is an additional license required if I want to install SSRS on the Sharepoint Box (which I have been told is the recommended practice) instead of the SQL Box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSRS, to be used in SharePoint Integrated Mode, must be installed on a server that has SharePoint installed and joined to the farm.  Obviously this would not be a good idea to install SharePoint on a Database Engine server if you can avoid it.

Install SSRS on your SharePoint server in Integrated mode.  Yes, you must license SQL Server (SSRS) on your SharePoint Server, the license is not included with the Database Engine installation.

As always, however, when it comes to Microsoft Licensing... contact [Microsoft Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/contact-us.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for posting. I am a little unsure of the licenses we currently hold. But I am going to go ahead and try to install SSRS on the sharepoint box and see what happens. I would use the same setup file as sql2008 but just not check database engine underfeatures right?

Comment: That is correct, just just select the Reporting Services component.  Integrating with SharePoint happens via the Reporting Services configuration tool.

Comment: I have setup a named instance on my SQl2008 box without reporting services. I am installing sharepoint using least privileges approach(spadmin,spfarm and spsql accts). I use spsql to run the mssqlserver and server agent services on my sql2008 box. Now when I install reporting services on my sharepoint box would I select only the reporting and analysis features (not the database engine) and the shared features? Additionally would I use the same spsql acct to run services here as well?

Comment: Only select Reporting Services and create a new ssrs account (you also may want a SSRS Unattended Execution account).

Comment: I can create a new AD SSRS Service account. But could you please explain the need of the SSRS unattended execution accnt. And to reconfirm again, Dont I need to use the spsql acct (that I used to run the mssqlserver and server agent services on my SQl2008 box) to run the same services on this installation on the sharepoint box as well.

Comment: The Unattended Execution account is used for connecting to other data sources when you don't want to pass user authentication.  It isn't required.  No, you should not use the spsql account.

Comment: Thanks. I know this a little off the original Question posted but would I be using spSSRS (The new service account I created to run the SSRS service) as the trusted account while integrating from Sharepoint CA and in the repoting services configuration wizard as well or can I just use spFarm? If possible could you please point me to a walkthrough link that I can possibly use.

Comment: Select Trusted Account and the account used in the username/password box could even be your own account, given you have appropriate rights to all the Web Applications.  This account is only used to modify permissions to allow the SSRS account to access the Content Databases.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I got it going and am able to render a report in a SSRS web part. But god is it slow!!

Comment: Install a SQL 2008 SP or SP + CU on your SSRS box if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do it on SQL server. He has it right: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/35501/3569

I see too many people install it on SQL server.  Install it on its own box or WFE server.